# Prove $\frac1{\sqrt x}$ is continous on $(0,\infty)$. Stuck on last line!

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inverse

Let $f(x) = \frac1{\sqrt x}$ for $x\in(0,\infty)$. Given $\varepsilon>0$ and $x_0\in(0,\infty)$, show there exists $\delta>0$ such that $$|x-x_0|<\delta$$ implies that  $$|f(x)-f(x_0)| <\varepsilon.$$

Now $$|f(x)-f(x_0)| = \left|\frac 1{\sqrt x} - \frac1{\sqrt{x_0}}\right| =  \frac{|x_0-x|}{|x_0\sqrt x + x\sqrt{x_0}|}.$$

This was done by putting them under one denominator, and multiplying top and bottom by the conjugate of the top.

Where do I go from here?

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: did you edit this for me? if so thank you so much

Comment: **Hint:** choose $\delta$ so that $\delta < \sqrt{x}/2$ *and* $\delta < \epsilon/(2\sqrt{x})$.

Comment: You have put delta in terms of epsilon and the square root of x, but is this allowed? aren't we trying to prove 1/square root of x is continous? wouldn't your final line assume the very thing we are trying to prove?

Comment: @anna_xox No, as long as you can ensure $\delta > 0$, the dependency can have any form $\delta = f(\epsilon, x_0)$.

Comment: @omnomnomnomnom  how did you know what to choose for delta?

Comment: @anna_xox I really would like to help here, so please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I just want to give you the best answer I can give you.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful. And just to confirm what I think is true, you chose delta to be x_0/2 because you wanted something less than x. In theory, you could have just as easily chosen x_0/3 or x_0/10 if you wanted  and this would have worked as well, right? I do understand  the logic though, by  having x_0/2 less than x, we reduce what is under the surd, which decreases the denominator, which increases the whole asnwer, which renders the inequality true. Thank you

Comment: You're correct.  That initial $\delta$ is not a unique value.  We need to ensure that $x>0$ so we cannot choose $\delta = 1/2$ for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First choose $\delta=\frac{x_0}{2}$.  Then, for this value of $\delta$, $x$ is in the interval $\frac{x_0}{2}<x<\frac{3x_0}{2}$. Then, we have the following

$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} -\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_0}}\right|&=\left|\frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x_0}}{\sqrt{xx_0}} \right|\\
&=\left|\frac{x-x_0}{\sqrt{xx_0}(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x_0})} \right|\\
&\le \frac{\left|x-x_0\right|}{\sqrt{(\frac12x_0)x_0}\;\left(\sqrt{\frac12x_0}+\sqrt{x_0}\right)} \\
&<\frac{\left|x-x_0\right|}{x_0^{3/2}}\\
&< \epsilon
\end{align}$$

when $|x-x_0|<\delta =\min (x_0/2,x_0^{3/2}\epsilon)$.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: I added one more comment above, where all the other comments are.

Comment: Also in your second last night, the bottom line doesn't simplify to a perfect x0^(3/2) so did you eliminate the surds or am I missing something?

Comment: I used the fact that $\sqrt{1/2}(1+\sqrt{1/2})=1/2+\sqrt{1/2}>1$.  So, the reciprocal of the LHS is less than $1$.